# SUBTOTAL not displaying results?

Tags: excel

I have a table with filtered results from another sheet and am trying to use a SUBTOTAL formula at the bottom, but for some reason it's not working, since it's simply blank.

Here is an example from one of the columns:

[image: Example]

Each column has the following formula returning values seen in the image:

```
=IFERROR(MID(LEFT(Functions!M3,FIND("*",Functions!M3)-1),FIND("@",Functions!M3)+1,LEN(Functions!M3)),"")
```

And the SUBTOTAL at the bottom is:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,[Missing Miles])
```

I would be thankful for any help I can get regarding this.

Cheers,

Francis

Comment: you cannot sum text. put a double unary in front of mid in the first formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because MID returns text and not a number.  Use this:

```
=IFERROR(--MID(LEFT(Functions!M3,FIND("*",Functions!M3)-1),FIND("@",Functions!M3)+1,LEN(Functions!M3)),0)
```

as the formula in the cells.  it will force the text that looks like a number to an actual number.

Comment: One last related question @Scott-Craner, I tried this with another column which retrieves data from another sheet, however using the following formula:
RIGHT(Functions!M3,LEN(Functions!M3)-FIND("%",Functions!M3))

Which results with a fraction 1/8.

I tried your suggested approach with this, but it then displays 43108 for the fraction 1/8. I formatted the cells accordingly but no luck

Comment: That is because Excel sees `1/8` as a date.  Excel does not understand fractions as a number but as text.  You would need to parse the parts and do the division to get the decimal.  @Francis  Try to do that and if you get stuck you can ask another question later.

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thanks again and sorry for the questions. I'm new to this.